# How do i reference user root directory path on windows machine

Tags: windows, electron

How do i run this command on a windows machine:

````
HOME=~/.electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=1.2.3 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers```


I want to achieve something like this:


```cd /path-to-module/
C:\Users\T-Bills\.electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=1.2.3 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers```
````

Comment: Use %userprofile%\.electron-gyp

Comment: Thanks. but it didn't work as expected. i got this error: ```'C:\Users\T-Bills\.electron-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: Does [app.getPath('home')](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) not give you what you want?

Comment: No, I want to run the command in command prompt (CMD)

Comment: I've sold the issue myself. I installed Git bash and run the command in git bash terminal. Thanks all.